# How to know the row index from DataTable object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I'm getting a value from DataGridView, and based on particular I want to know its row index using DataTable object. For instance, if I get the value "this", then I want to know its index in table. May I know how should I done

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If that value "this" belongs to a `Non-Primary-Key Column` in `DataTable`, you may get more than one rows returned.

To find a value in `DataTable`, use `DataTable`'s `Select()` method:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select("Column1 = 'this'");
```

Once you get the row(s), you can find its index using `DataTable.Rows.IndexOf()` method.

I suggest you find a better way to locate your row from `DataTable`. May be look for row using a value that belongs to a `Primary Key Column`.

It would be great to know why you want to do this. Someone could come up with a better solution.

Comment: If I am using int nIndex = DataSet.DataTable[0].Rows.Indexof() it gives me error message.

Comment: @RushabhShah: Pass a `DataRow` object in `IndexOf()` as a parameter.

Comment: question is how do I get the current DataRow in the FIRST PLACE? Please expand

Answer (score 5):

```
DataRow[] result = tableName.Select("Group >= 'Commentary - Yes'");
  if (result.Length > 0)
     {
          int SelectedIndex =tableName.Rows.IndexOf(result[0]);
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.Data;

DataRowView row1 = (DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

int idx11 = row1.Row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row1.Row);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the author's question, please consider providing an explanation as code is just a sample and SDK's/API's may change over time.