# DataTable: How to get item value with row name and column name? (VB)

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a simple `DataTable` where one of the columns contains unique values. For example:

```
ColumnName1   ColumnName2
value1        35
value2        44
value3        10
```

Because I know that value 1, 2 and 3 will always be different one from another, I would like to get a value of this table only using *ColumnName2* and *one of the values of ColumnName1*.
That would for example be:

```
searchedValue = DataTable.Rows("value3").Item("ColumnName2) 
'result would be 10
```

I tried the following examples unsuccessfully:

- [with the DataTable.Select method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525550/how-to-know-the-row-index-from-datatable-object): returns an array of rows, but I only need one
- [with the DataTable.Rows.IndexOf method](http://forums.asp.net/t/1305442.aspx/1): if I understood well, I need to provide the whole row contents for it to be found with this method.

Comment: Call `FirstOrDefault()` on the result of `Select`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
Dim rows() AS DataRow = DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'")
If rows.Count > 0 Then
     searchedValue = rows(0).Item("ColumnName2") 
End If
```

With `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Dim row AS DataRow = DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'").FirstOrDefault()
If Not row Is Nothing Then
     searchedValue = row.Item("ColumnName2") 
End If
```

In C#:

```
var row = DataTable.Select("ColumnName1 = 'value3'").FirstOrDefault();
if (row != null)
     searchedValue = row["ColumnName2"];
```

Comment: Why did you not propose your solution with `FirstOrDefault()` as answer? I found it the most convenient. Does it have drawbacks?

Comment: This is the same thing. When you use `FirstOrDefault` you need to check if the returned row is null instead of checking the count.

Comment: can u please tell me the same thing in c#

Comment: what if value3 contains single quotes ? like va'lue 3 how to handle it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
'Create a class to hold the pair...

        Public Class ColumnValue
            Public ColumnName As String
            Public ColumnValue As New Object
        End Class

    'Build the pair...

        For Each row In [YourDataTable].Rows

              For Each item As DataColumn In row.Table.Columns
                Dim rowValue As New ColumnValue
                rowValue.ColumnName = item.Caption
                rowValue.ColumnValue = row.item(item.Ordinal)
                RowValues.Add(rowValue)
                rowValue = Nothing
              Next

        ' Now you can grab the value by the column name...

        Dim results = (From p In RowValues Where p.ColumnName = "MyColumn" Select  p.ColumnValue).FirstOrDefault    

        Next
```

Comment: @stephenCarver Hi i know its been a while since you took a look at this, but I am trying to write a similar for loop to do the exact thing; my question is that would i need to use a datatable? Can I run this for loop for data in a  gridview  or dataview and do the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

```
For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

    ListV.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item("STU_NUMBER").ToString)
    ListV.Items(i).SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item("FNAME").ToString & " " & dt.Rows(i).Item("MI").ToString & ". " & dt.Rows(i).Item("LNAME").ToString)
    ListV.Items(i).SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item("SEX").ToString)

Next
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
DataTable.Rows[RowNo].ItemArray[columnIndex].ToString()
```

(This is C# code. Change this to VB equivalent)

Comment: The thing is that I do not have the row number. Only one of the values of `ColumnName1` that are, in my case, strings.

Comment: In VB.net: `DataTable.Rows(RowNo).ItemArray(columnNo).ToString()`