# Get row index if some column value is equal to something

Tags: vb.net, datatable

In this datatable there are no duplicates, I need the row index where column x value equals 2. I would do it like this:

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To mtable.Rows.Count - 1
            If mtable.Rows(i)("x") = 2 Then
                rowIndex = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

I will be calling this process multiple times per second. Is there a faster way to do this in .NET?

Comment: There are certainly different ways to achieve the same result.  But this one is probably the fastest.  Some Indexing might help, depends on your dataset.

Comment: I agree with Dan-o, you also could change the `If mtable.Rows(i)("x") = 2 Then` to the column Index of `x` column, for sample: `If mtable.Rows(i)(2) = 2 Then`

Comment: I'd initialize rowIndex to -1 so that you can tell if the value wasn't found.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386827/datatable-how-to-get-item-value-with-row-name-and-column-name-vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple times per second is a bit vague - tens or thousands?

You could create a hash table mapping the value of "x" to the row number:

```
Dim nLookups = mtable.Rows.Count - 1
Dim lookupHash As New Hashtable(nLookups)
For i = 0 To nLookups
    lookupHash.Add(CInt(mtable.Rows(i)("x")), i)
Next
```

then

```
Dim rowSought As Integer = -1
If lookupHash.ContainsKey(2) Then
    rowSought = lookupHash(2)
End If
```

Or if the range of possible values of "x" is suitable, you could use an array to map the value to the row number.

Comment: No more than 200 records, code in question is still fine but can it get faster  with hash table mapping?

Comment: @user1570048 If that's all the records you have, then if speed is a problem it might be worth considering that the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

DataTable select could work, i think it should be faster than iterating over the collection of rows.

```
    var index = mtable.Rows.IndexOf(mtable.Select("x = 2").FirstOrDefault());
```