# How to prevent adding repeated data into a listbox?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a bunch os items in *lst1* which I want to put into *lst2* but without repeating them on each **ListBox**.

**Interface I'm using:**

[image]

This is working, but you may need it to understand my doubt.

```
Dim dtTa_Enc As DataTable = New DataTable("Ta_Enc")
Dim dsTa As DataSet = New DataSet("Ta_E")

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand
adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query

connection.Open()
adapter.Fill(ds, "tables")
connection.Close()

lst1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tables")
lst1.DisplayMember = "name"
lst1.ValueMember = "codta"

dtTa_Enc.Columns.Add("codta")
dtTa_Enc.Columns.Add("name")
dsTa.Tables.Add(dtTa_Enc)
lst2.DataSource = dsTa.Tables("Tables")
lst2.DisplayMember = "name"
lst2.ValueMember = "codta"
dtTa_Enc.Rows.Add(lst1.ValueMember, lst1.GetItemText(lst1.SelectedItem))
```

**Doubt:** 

Now, The user presses a button to add his selected item of *lst1* to *lst2*. Easy! However, what if he tries to add the same item. Can VB.Net stop him from doing it?

```
If not dtTa_Enc.find("codTa = " + lst1.valuemember) Then
    dtTa_Enc.Rows.Add(lstTabelas.ValueMember, lstTabelas.GetItemText(lstTabelas.SelectedItem))
End If
```

Comment: A modification of this code didn't work, but It was the best I found until now:[DateTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386827/datatable-how-to-get-item-value-with-row-name-and-column-name-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the Add event handler, you could place some logic at the begining to prevent adding the repeated item.

```
    Dim lst1Selected As String = CType(lst1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)("name").ToString
    Dim flag As Integer = 0
    For Each item As Object In lst2.Items
        Dim istr As String = CType(item, DataRowView)("name").ToString
        If istr = lst1Selected Then
            flag = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If flag = 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: I think we're getting closer, but that's not it.

Comment: Because your solution gave me this exception:"Conversion of type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid"

Comment: Now, your code is working perfectly. Thank you very much, Joe! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate through your *lst2* to determine whether any of the values match your selected item, `lst1.SelectedItem`.

So loop,

```
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For Each itm As String in lst2.Items
        If itm = lst1.SelectedItem Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not found Then
        'Add it.
    End If
```

Or you can simply use the `Contains` method:

```
    If Not lst2.Items.Contains(lst1.SelectedItem) Then
        'Add it.
    End if.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex!

Comment: But your first solution gave me this exception:"Conversion of type 'DataRowView' to type 'String' is not valid"

Comment: Your last although it runs, the lst2 is still receiving repeated "items"