# How to scroll to first record again using OracleDataReader class or another class?

Tags: java, vb.net, oracle, translate, datareader

I'm migrating a Java application to VB.Net and I try to translate following Java code

```
Statement stmt 
    = conx.createStatement
        (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE
        ,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
        );
ResultSet rsSheet = stmt.executeQuery(sSql);
bStatus = rsSheet.next();
...
bStatus = rsSheet.first();
```

In this code, a **scrollable** ResultSet is used. I can read the records returned by `executeQuery()` function and when I have terminated to read them, I can read it again **without** interrogating the Database a second time.

You can find some information on ResultSet here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

My translated code is following

```
Dim cmd = conx.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = sSql
Dim rsSheet as OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
bStatus = rsSheet.Read()
...
bStatus = rsSheet.? 'how to read first record again ?
```

But I don't find how to do so that `OracleDataReader` is scrollable ?

I can read the ResultSet from first to last record but I cannot read it again.

The only simple solution that I found to read all these records again is to call `ExecuteReader()` function a second time.

QUESTIONS

Is `OracleDataReader` Class scrollable ? How ?

Does another Class exist to do the job ? Which ?

PS: using Linq is not solution because SQL statements are executed in an environnement where Database structure is unknown. It is impossible to create entities.

Comment: [Mini-ORM as Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/)? A DataTable?

Comment: You're right; you have to ExecuteReader again.. As others have noted you can load the data into memory with a DataTable etc, but if your result set is too large for memory, you have to execute it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataReader is one way only. Use a DataTable. This is an in memory representation of the result set. You can also use a DataTable to as a DataSource for various controls. You can use Linq on a DataTable.AsEnumerable()

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sSql = "Your command text"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OracleConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OracleCommand(sSql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    'Code to read data.
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The simplest way to see what is in the DataTable is to display it in a DataGridView if this is WinForms.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.
```

To access a specific row and column.

```
Dim s = dt.Rows(1)("ColName").ToString
```

The Rows collection starts with index 0 and the column name is from you Select statement. You then need to convert to the datatype with .ToString or Cint(), CDbl() etc. as this returns an object.

Comment: Thanks! That is working for me. The only 'litle' problem is that methods used to get values in DataRow are distinct from methods used in OracleDataReader. Example: GetString() doesn't exist in DataRow. Following link are also interesting [DataTable: How to get item value with row name and column name? (VB)
]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386827/datatable-how-to-get-item-value-with-row-name-and-column-name-vb

Comment: Please see EDIT to my answer.

Comment: OK. But your first answer is enough for me. My last comment is only a litle remark about how to get column's values in a row. Your remark about DataGridView is not interesting for me ... because my program is a batch program. But it can be useful for another user ;-) But I don't understand why you use 'EDIT' as title ?

Comment: @schlebe The Edit just indicates that it was not a part of the original answer. :-)