# How to find the Row index in collections in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to  find a value in collection using "collection contains value" action in Collection manipulation VBO. I want to read the row index of the value read. Can someone guide me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to completing this:

1. **Loop over your collection and compare the search term to each Collection item.** This is computationally expensive (especially for large collections), but it will yield you the right result with minimal development time.
2. **Modify the Collection Manipulation object** - Duplicate the pre-existing "Filter Collection" Action from the Utility - Collection Manipulation object, and modify the code stage that leverages the previous calls to `DataTable`'s `select` and utilizes it against the `indexOf` functionality to retrieve the index of the row you're searching for ([relevant SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525550/how-to-know-the-row-index-from-datatable-object)). This is ideal for larger collections and would seem to me to be generally more sustainable long-term.